# TI-Nspire saving 2 different variables from solve

Tags: ti-nspire

So i have two functions defined as
`f(x)=x^2-x-6` and `g(x)=x+2`
I need to find the points where `f(x)=g(x)`
When i

```
solve(f(x)=g(x),x)
```

i get two values;
`x=-2` and `x=4`
My question is, can i define the two values individually from the solve so i get
`x1=-2` and `x2=4 ?`
I've tried getting the text out as a string using `string(solve` and a version of
`res:=solve({x+2*y=5,x-y=2},{x,y})` from another post. But this doesn't seem to work for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try step by step:

```
f:=x^2-x-6
g:=x+2
res:=solve(f=g,x)
```

ans: x=−2 or x=4

```
l1:=exp▶list(res,{x})
```

ans: [[4][−2]]
At what step are you failing and what error youre getting?

Comment: The thing i can't seem to figure out with this method is when i define x1=-2 and x2=4 it gets written as x1=[-2] and x2=[4] and therefore i can't use them for further calculations in my document. For context i am trying to use x1 and x2 for definite integral, and when i try to input them in definite integral i get the error "Argument error"

Comment: Yeah, it packs them like a matrix, not vector. So, you can type: x1:=l1[1,1] and x2:=l1[2,1] to get scalars.

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, and i got it working now. Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Ok, but in this case (if youre sure that f and g are both polynomials), i think that polyroots is faster:
li:= polyroots (f-g,x):
x1:= li[1]:
x2:= li[2]

Answer (score 0):

Hej Rasmus,

The simplest solution is to use `zeros` which finds zeros (nulpunkter) of a function.
Two functions `f(x)` and `g(x)` are equal, when their difference is zero.

```
f(x) = g(x)    <=>   f(x)-g(x) = 0
```

You can find the solutions like this:

```
zeros(f(x)-g(x))
```

And to store them in variables:

```
xs := zeros( f(x)-g(x) )
x1 := xs[1]
x2 := xs[2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This works! But do you know of a way to get the two results defined separately from the solve command? Or is the only way to find a work around each time?

Comment: What do you mean by separately here?  

You can, write `zeros( f(x)-g(x))[1]` and `zeros(f(x)-g(x))[2]` but that it is inefficient (it will solve the equation twice).

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, english is not my first language. I will try to explain myself as good as possible.  What i mean is if i have an equation, with more than one answer, that i have to use `solve` to solve and zeros can't be applied, is there a way to define them individually like zeros( f(x)-g(x))[1] and zeros(f(x)-g(x))[2] but instead something like `solve(f(x)-g(x),x)[1]` and `solve(f(x)-g(x),x)[2]` (I know these two solve solutions do not work, but i hope it shows what i am trying to accomplish to learn to do in TI-Nspire)

Comment: The difference between `solve` and `zeros` is that `solve` gives you an expression (udtryk) as a result, like `x=42`, and `zeros` gives you a list of roots `{42}`. Since you want to store the solution `42` it is easier to use `zeros` than `solve` since `zeros` give you the numbers directly. Now given an expression like `x=42` you can use `right` to get the number. What complicates matters is that you have multiple solutions. Therefore you need to use `exp▶list` first to turn the result of `solve` into a list, then use `right`. Note that internally `solve(f(x)=g(x),x)` just calls `zeros`.

Comment: In short, the situation "i have an equation, with more than one answer, that i have to use solve to solve and zeros can't be applied" is a bit silly - why not use `zeros`? (If you are worried that a reader doesn't get - simply add a line explaining what it does).

Comment: I thank you for your time and on the insight of TI-Nspire, you were a giant help!